# Can't select Object of Array with correct index

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

We are developping a game for monsters and hero's.
Upon intialization of the hero, he has a given strength. (in this case 50)
Strength is a double with precision of two digits.
According to the strength of the hero, his capacity for carrying various Items is initialized by following rules:

If the strength is between 1 and 10 (inclusive), then it's strength multiplied with 10.
Strength between 10.01 and 20(inclusive), is a capacity out of following array:
{115,130,150,175,200,230,260,300,350,400}. The index is determined by subtracting 10 from the strength and rounding this number downward. (As strength is represented by a double).
Strength higher than 20 is by calculating the capacity if the hero had strength minus 10 and multiplying this by 4.

Here is the code I have for calculating the capacity.

```
    private final int[] capacities = new int[]{115,130,150,175,200,230,260,300,350,400}; //initialized array of integers.
    public double calculateCapacity(){
    if(1<=getStrength() && getStrength()<=10){
        return getStrength()*10; //method does this correctly
    }
    else if(10<getStrength() && getStrength()<=20){
        return this.capacities[(int) (getStrength()-10.01)]; //Here it already goes wrong. 
    }
    else{
        double valueToReturn = 0;
        double tempStrength = getStrength();
        while(tempStrength >20){
            valueToReturn++;
            tempStrength = tempStrength - 10;
        }
        System.out.println((int) (tempStrength-10.01));
        return Math.pow(4,valueToReturn)*getCapacities()[(int) (tempStrength-10.01)];
    }


}
```

The outputs of the system print is: 9

It goes wrong with the last return statement. Where java for some reason does not want to take the ninth integer out of the array. I constantly get NullPointerExceptions, but I think the index is correct and the array is also properly initialized. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work? (getCapacities is Basic getter)

Comment: *Strength is a double with precision of two digits* doubles do not have any precision

Comment: Are you sure the array has been initialized at that point?
Could calculateCapacity somehow get called from the constructor of the class?
Why are using capacities in one place and getCapacities() in the other?

Comment: `NullPointerException` means there must be a reference, otherwise you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Please post `getCapacities()` and the full stack trace

Comment: @Raffaele I adjusted the double so it has the two digits precision.

Comment: @amahfouz It is possible that it hasn't been intialized at that point now that you say it. I changed it to a static variable and now it works. Always the little problems that knock me over... Thanks :)

Comment: Good! It should be static anyways.
Please mark my answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array must be null then.

Are you sure the array has been initialized at that point? 
Could calculateCapacity() somehow get called from the constructor of the class? 
What is the stacktrace?
Why are using capacities in one place and getCapacities() in the other?